# phpseclib Warning: unpack() [function.unpack]: Type C: not enough inpu

Tags: php, phpseclib

Some SFTP credential works fine for below open source, but some credential throwing below error. what is the root cause for the below error, i saw some threads they posted some workouts, but those solutions does not worked for me.

Why i am getting below error, what will be the solution.

open source: phpseclib
Error: Bellow Error

```
Warning: unpack() [function.unpack]: Type C: not enough input, need 1, have 0 in \Net\SSH2.php on line 1469

Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in \Net\SSH2.php on line 1469
```

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L1538

Answer (score 0):

What is on your line 1469? The version you linked to has this on line 1469:

```
while ($this->decrypt_block_size > strlen($iv)) {
```

Your link is to line 1538, which is this:

```
            break;
```

If you could post the three lines before and after, too, that'd be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older question and it's been down-rated, but I am actually having the same error. It happens intermittently, so it's hard to troubleshoot. My errors are referencing line 2127 of *\Net\SSH2.php*. Here is that line, plus a few surrounding lines:

```
    2121 $response = $this->_get_binary_packet();
    2122 if ($response === false) {
    2123    user_error('Connection closed by server');
    2124    return false;
    2125 }

    2127 extract(unpack('Ctype', $this->_string_shift($response, 1)));

    2129 switch ($type) {
    2130    case NET_SSH2_MSG_USERAUTH_PASSWD_CHANGEREQ: // in theory, the password can be changed
    2131        if (defined('NET_SSH2_LOGGING')) {
```

This is the syntax that I'm using to copy a file from an external server to my own after logging in:

```
$sftp->get('/remote/file/path/file.csv', 'myfile.csv');
```

Here's the link to the page: https://files.maf.org/mp/forms/ChangePL.php

Actually, that page isn't accessed directly normally, but inside an iframe via https://www.maf.org/change

I will say that I've never produced the error when going to the direct link; only accessing it from the parent page via the iframe. Why would that be the case?